# Ampersand and square brackets priority

Tags: c++, c, operators, operator-precedence

I see a lot of programmers using brackets around an expression, e.g. :

```
&(tab[i]) /* I use `&tab[i]`. */
```

I think it isn't necessary, because the `[]` operator has a greater priority than `&` operator. So, why do they use brackets ?

Comment: Probably "add bracket where you are not sure"?

Comment: teach them to use `tab+i` rather than `&(tab[i])`

Comment: That's ugly. Superfluous use of brackets sometimes indicates a programmer who isn't very sure of themselves. Taken to extreme it can affect code legibility.

Comment: @Anonymous: That seems like a spectaculary bad idea in c++ where `tab` can easily be a `vector` or some other class with an overloaded `operator+`. It is very unlikely that `tab+i` does the same thing as `&(tab[i])` in that case (if it even compiles).

Comment: Ok, thanks for all your answers.

Comment: @john: In my experience, programmers who aren't sure of themselves tend to make fewer mistakes than those who are. I'd rather see too many parentheses (within reason) than too few.

Comment: I'm always pretty sure of myself when I write a load of code.  I'm pretty sure it won't compile first time, pretty sure it won't link and completely sure that, once successfully built, it won't work to spec and will require a pile of debugging.   I cannot remember a single time that I encountered a bug in my code due to incorrect operator precedence - it's always some other screwup.  I also can't remember looking at old code, whether mine or not, and thinking 'this code has too many parentheses'.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For sake of clarity. Not everyone has all the operator precedences memorized.

Comment: In other words, it's for the benefit of programmers who don't know what they're doing. Seems like it's solving the wrong problem.

Comment: 'In other words, it's for the benefit of programmers who don't know what they're doing' - that's all of them, then, or are there some developers out there who have never generated any bugs?

Comment: @PeteBecker How many programmers have all the operator precedences memorized? How about for every language they know? I personally use at least 3 different languages regularly at my job. Do you expect me to memorize the grammar for all the languages before I even attempt to write a line of code? Even if you had them memorized, humans are fallible, your memory might slip. Finally, readability is an important part of code, your code should be accessible not only to yourself, but others as well.

Comment: How do you write any code if you don't know the language grammar? Yes, readability is important; that's why redundant parenthese are a bad idea: they make readers look for something unusual that isn't there.

Comment: @PeteBecker Are you saying you have every rule of the c++ language memorized? That is what I meant. Perhaps I misused the term grammar. The point I'm making is, languages, especially c++ are very large and have many many rules. I doubt there are many people who have the entire language rules memorized.

Comment: Well, he does call himself a "C++ expert", whatever that means.

Comment: When I was at Uni, punching FORTRAN onto Hollerith cards for batch execution, I was TAUGHT to use redundant parentheses to highlight precedence and improve readabilty.  I've changed my views on a lot of subjects over the years, (OK, decades), but this is not one of them.

Comment: @anio: I am sure he thinks that everyone who has not, and everyone who has problems in parsing any c++ code at all, should not be using c++. or so.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say there are basically two reasons:

- The programmer isn't sure about operator precedence and codes defensively
- To make absolutely clear for every reader (who may not have the precendence memorized) what is going on

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed not necessary because postfix operators always have higher precedence than unary operators.

The people that use parens in `&(tab[i])` use them for the same reason they use it in the expression `(8 * 5) / 2`.

Answer (score 2):

In a recent question, someone had to decypher code like `--p---> x < 0`. Just like your code, that code is unambiguous as per C++ parsing rules.

However, humans don't always remember all of these complex rules, so many programmers make it a habit to use parens in situations that might look not totally clear to others (or to themselves). It is documenting the real intention of the code.

This is a Good Thing To Do™

Comment: The fact that some people write bad code doesn't justify adding unnecessary parentheses in good code.

Comment: Good code does have unnecessary parentheses - it makes it easier to debug, maintain and enhance.  If all redundancy was removed from source code, it would be semi-obfuscated, unreadable gunge, full if single-letter, 'a,b,c,d...' var names and magic numbers.  The object code generated is the same and will work equally well, or equally badly, either way.

Answer (score 1):

Because they find it clearer? Especially for something like this:

```
int *a[];
```

Is that a pointer to an array of ints or an array of pointers to int?